# Code to get "magic squares" not working

Tags: python

I am having problems with making magic squares. A magic square is a square of numbers which has the same sum on all of its rows and columns.
E.g.:
1 2 14
3 13 1
13 2 2
I have no idea what is wrong with my code, but it is supposed to read three numbers from magicin.txt and bruteforce squares from there and write the output in magicout.txt

I am coding this because it is in the AIO practice questions. The website is:
http://orac.amt.edu.au/cgi-bin/train/problem.pl?set=aio16int&problemid=902

If further clarification or anything is needed, please comment. The code is here(It has a bunch of useless print and "press enter to exit" statements for debugging):

```
def Main():
file=open("magicin.txt","r")
magicin=file.read()
file.close()
num1="" 
num2="" 
num3=0 
num4="" 
num5=0 
num6=0 
num7=0 
num8=0 
num9=0 
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(magicin) if x == " "]
splitSpace2=indices[1]
splitSpace=indices[0]
for x in range(splitSpace):
    num1+=magicin[x]
for x in range(splitSpace+1,splitSpace2):
    num2+=magicin[x]
for x in range(splitSpace2+1,len(magicin)):
    num4+=magicin[x]
num1=int(num1)
num2=int(num2)
num4=int(num4)
for x in range(20):
    num3=x
    sum=num1+num2+num3
    num7=sum-num1
    if num7<0:
        print("Falied with num7="+str(num7))
    else:
        for y in range(20):
            num5=y
            for z in range(20):
                num6=z
                if num6+num5+num4==sum:
                    for a in range(20):
                        num8=a
                        if num8+num2+num5==sum:
                            for b in range(20):
                                num9=b
                                if num9+num8+num7==sum and num9+num6+num3==sum:
                                    answer=[str(num1),str(num2),str(num3),str(num4),str(num5),str(num6),str(num7),str(num8),str(num9)]
                                    file=open("magicout.txt","w")
                                    file.write(answer[0]+" "+answer[1]+" "+answer[2]+"\n"+answer[3]+" "+answer[4]+" "+answer[5]+"\n"+answer[6]+" "+answer[7]+" "+answer[8])
                                    file.close()
                                    return
                                else:
                                    print("failed with num9+num8+num7==sum and num9+num6+num3==sum"+" "+str(num9)+" "+str(num8)+" "+str(num7)+" "+str(sum),str(num9),str(num6),str(num3),str(sum))

                        else:
                            print("Failed with num8+num2+num5==sum",str(num8),str(num2),str(num5),str(sum))

                else:
                    print("Failed with num6="+str(num6)+" num5="+str(num5),"num4="+str(num4),"sum="+str(sum))
    if x==19:
        print(num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7,num8,num9)
        wait=input("")
        file=open("magicout.txt","w")
        file.write("none")
        file.close()
answer=Main()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently finished this problem and it is actually deceptively easy. In normal magic squares, you cannot repeat any numbers. However, the AIO problem allows you to repeat numbers as often as you want. Due to this, a surprising symmetry arises.

If I let the magic number be `m`, I could write out my magic square in the following form:

```
a       b       m-(a+b
c       m-(b+c) b
m-(a+c) c       a
```

Due to this, You can create a magic square with simple math. You simply need to test for `m` so that the greater of `m-(a+c)` and `m-(a+b)` is between 1 and 20. All you actually need to do to see if this is true is to see if the middle number of your square is greater than 1. All the other numbers will always work, in every situation. From this, I made the following code in python:

```
infile = open("magicin.txt", "r")
outfile = open("magicout.txt", "w")
split = infile.readline().split()
n1 = int(split[0])
n2 = int(split[1])
n4 = int(split[2])
square = [ [n1, n2, 0], [n4, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
minmagic = max(square[0][0] + square[0][1], square[0][0] + square[1][0]) + 1 #lowest possible magic number
maxmagic = max(square[0][0] + square[0][1], square[0][0] + square[1][0]) +20 #highest possible magic number
for magic in range(minmagic, maxmagic + 1):
square[2][0] = magic - (square[0][0] + square[1][0]) #fill bottom left corner
square[0][2] = magic - (square[0][0] + square[0][1]) #fill top right corner
square[2][2] = square[0][0] #fill bottom right
square[2][1] = square[1][0] #fill bottom edge
square[1][2] = square[0][1] #fill right edge
square[1][1] = magic - (square[0][1] + square[2][1]) #fill middle of square
if square[1][1] > 0: # if middle is greater than 0, you've found a square, so break the for loop.
    break
outfile.write(str(square[0][0]) + " " + str(square[0][1]) + " " + str(square[0][2]) + "\n")
outfile.write(str(square[1][0]) + " " + str(square[1][1]) + " " + str(square[1][2]) + "\n")
outfile.write(str(square[2][0]) + " " + str(square[2][1]) + " " + str(square[2][2]) + "\n")
```

I hope this helped!

Comment: it gets interesting if you were asked to produce all possible magic squares of size n...

Comment: @IrmendeJong If you were to allow repeating numbers and the semi-magic nature of these squares (diagonals don't matter), the number of possible squares would surely grow massively as n increased. Finding 'real' magic squares, on the other hand, is another matter all together.